# Parse Apache Common Log Format request urls containing Space

Tags: regex, apache, logging

I am trying to parse the Apache common log format logs using the following regular expression in Python

```
APACHE_ACCESS_LOG_PATTERN = '^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)" (\d{3}) (\S+)'
```

My typical logs are in the format of

```
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:04 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium.gif HTTP/1.0" 401 0
```

but many of my URL's contain spaces, how do I parse them ex:

```
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:04 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium large  .gif HTTP/1.0" 401 0
```

Currently I am parsing using this code

```
match = re.search(APACHE_ACCESS_LOG_PATTERN, logline)
if match is None:
    print>>output_file, logline
    return
size_field = match.group(9)
if size_field == '-':
    size = long(0)
else:
    size = long(match.group(9))
return (Access(
    ipAddress     = match.group(1),
    clientIdentd = match.group(2),
    userId       = match.group(3),
    dateTime     = parse_apache_time(match.group(4)),
    method        = match.group(5),
    endpoint      = match.group(6),
    protocol      = match.group(7),
    responseCode = int(match.group(8)),
    contentSize  = size
), 1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that spaces are not automatically encoded into `%20` in the log?

Comment: Yes, the logs do not encode the spaces automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So, if Apache doesn't encode spaces automatically, try to modify your regex this way:

`APACHE_ACCESS_LOG_PATTERN = '^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (.+?) (\S+)" (\d{3}) (\S+)'`

Comment: Hi @umka, I have used the pattern but I am getting a match error for the size field. Please refer my question, I have modified it, I could not put all the code here

Comment: Note the number of capturing groups `()` in my example

Comment: I then how can I extract both the endpoint and HTTP protocol, using this regex?

Comment: that worked, one last question, I have checked the out of format logs and gound out some of them as "215.145.83.92 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:41 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-71/movies/movies.html" 200 3089", i.e. they dont have HTTP protocol, how to handle this. Thanks

Comment: You can make the match group for protocol optional by putting a ```?``` after it like: ```(\S+)?```.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me to get the whitespaces. It is a non-greedy solution that pulls up everything between double quotes, including whitespaces.

```
^(\S+) - - \[([\w:\/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(.*?)" (\d{3}) (\d+)
                                        ^^^^
```